# C#: sequence from min to max

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get a **sequence** of integers **from a value A to a value B**.

For example `A=3` and `B=9`. Now I want to create a sequence `3,4,5,6,7,8,9` with one line of code and without a loop. I played around with `Enumerable.Range`, but I find no solution that works.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Given that the answers are all likely to use Enumerable.Range, it would really have helped if you'd shown what you'd already tried, and said what happened.

Comment: @Marc & Ilya, That is a *lot* of easy points you guys just picked up.

Answer (score 22):

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1);
```

?

For info, though - personally I'd still be tempted to use a loop:

```
for(int i = min; i <= max ; i++) { // note inclusive of both min and max
    // good old-fashioned honest loops; they still work! who knew!
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
int A = 3;
int B = 9;
var seq = Enumerable.Range(A, B - A + 1);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", seq)); //prints 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

if you have lots and lots of numbers and the nature of their processing is streaming (you handle items one at a time), then you don't need to hold all of the in memory via array and it's comfortable to work with them via `IEnumerable<T>` interface.